# ¿Cómo tomar datos de un usuario y mostrarlos en mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Hola buenas madrugadas!! La pantalla la coloqué para que mirarán más o menos de que hablaba, como ya mencióne y reitero de nuevo yo estoy imprimiendo la tabla post  de la columna postear, el problema es que si yo hago un post (agrego datos) se agrega fácilmente   incluso en la captura se ven, ahora lo que requiero  es que solo se vean los post que hace ese usuario, por qué si salgo de la sesión y registro otro y me logueo, aparecen los post del otro usuario(cuenta) y se supone que debe estar vacío, así que requiero encontrar una solución para que cada usuario muestre en su  muro sus propios  post .  Ahora son dos tablas una users y la otra post  la users tiene los datos del usuario y el post  tiene un id la fecha y el postear(el contenido que se muestra en el muro )

```
<?php
  session_start();
 $conexion  =  mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','facebook') or die ('Problemas al conectar la base de datos');
 $select =  mysqli_query($conexion,"select postear from post INNER JOIN users ON  users.id=post.id ") or die ('La consulta select no se generó'.mysqli_error($conexion));
 if($select){
    mysqli_query($conexion, "insert into post(postear) values('$_REQUEST[publicar]')") or die
    ('Problemas con la sentencia select'.mysqli_error($conexion));
 }else {
     echo "Problemas con la inserción";
 }

?>
```

Esto es una de las cosas que he intentado fracasando .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La solución a mi problema fue el siguiente:

```
<?php
```

$server = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','facebook') or die('Problema con la base de datos');
$query =  mysqli_query($server,"select postear from post INNER  JOIN  users ON users.id=post.id_user where users.id=$_SESSION[id]")or die('problemas con la sentencia select favor de verificar'.mysqli_error($server));

?>
así pude mostrar solo los datos de un user en especifico.

Comment: Mejor que el pantallazo, que te ha quedado muy bien, envíanos las tablas a ver qué pinta tienen, y qué esperas obtener de la consulta que has compartido

Comment: David subí otra  descripción del problema, muchas gracias.

Comment: Cuando modifiques la pregunta, vete añadiendo información para que la persona nueva que la vea entienda todo el contexto desde el principio. Yo sé de qué hablas porque leí la versión original. Piensa que interactuamos para que esta pregunta pueda ayudar a otra persona con una dificultad similar a la tuya. SO no es una conversación, chat, foro, ni un soporte técnico. Lo que le falta a tu SQL es un `WHERE` para que muestre únicamente la información vinculada al usuario autentificado en el sistema. Pero necesitamos ver las tablas que has creado y qué esperas obtener para poder ayudarte.

Comment: te falta el `WHERE` algo asi  `select postear from post INNER JOIN users ON  users.id=post.id  WHERE users.id = 1`

Comment: Además del comentario anterior, la condición del JOIN debería ser algo como `users.id = post.user`, de lo contrario, creo que el diseño de tus tablas no es el adecuado, deja lugar a confusiones y, por tanto, es propenso a errores.

Comment: @Wilfredo Aleman tomé en cuenta su solución pero me tira error, de hecho yo quería usar la clapsula where pero no supe hacer la condición, más bien no supe con que hacerla.

Comment: Estan mal tus tablas.. como sabes de quien es cada post?

Comment: no guardes en un blob las imagenes... mejor guardalas en el disco, y guarda la ruta en la base de datos..

Comment: Buenas tardes, sugieres que en la tabla users coloque el post?

Comment: sugiero que leas sobre tercera forma normal en bases de datos, asi como tambien sobre normalizacion... tu problema esta en que estan mal las tablas.. si pones en la tabla user el post, como hace un usuario para hacer muchos posts?

Comment: por lo menos, en la tabla post tiene que decir que usuario lo posteo.. vuelvo a preguntarte.. como sabes de quien es cada post?

Comment: por medio del id se sabe quien posteo.  mira yo en la segunda tabla post tengo un id  ese yo pienso que debe ser Fk de la tabla users de la PK, algo así?

Comment: ok.. entonces ese id en realidad es id_usuario? entonces, para indicar que una fila es unica, usas id+fecha? entonces estaria ok (aunque lo ideal seria que ese id, fuera el id del post, y tuvieras otro campo que indicara el id del usuario). Entonces solo tenes que agregar el where como te dijeron arriba

Comment: intentaré hacer eso, entonces tendré el id del comentario y haré otro campo con el id del usuario y lo valido con eso

Comment: @gbianchi efectivamente la forma en que me sugirió fue  la correcta, puse un campo id_users donde valide que fuera igual a  mi campo id, después coloqué el where diciéndole  donde el id tiene que ser igual a mi id de sesión y listo.